# Config section of compose file not working with docker compose up

Tags: docker-compose

I am trying to use the docker image of RabbitMQ: `rabbitmq:3.11.6` with docker compose. Everything works as expected but now I have to change a default setting of RabbitMQ.

According to the [documentation](https://rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-file-location) of RabbitMQ in this case the settings are parsed from `/etc/rabbitmq/conf.d` directory. The easiest way would be to just inject a file to the image so it would be loaded by RabbitMQ at startup. To test it I made a new image based on `rabbitmq:3.11.6` adding the new file, and it worked fine:

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.11.6
COPY --chown=rabbitmq:rabbitmq --chmod=0664 rabbitmq.conf /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/20-consumer_timeout.conf
```

With this the extra file is successfully loaded by RabbitMQ at startup:

```
rabbit-1  |  Config file(s): /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/10-defaults.conf
rabbit-1  |                  /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/20-consumer_timeout.conf
rabbit-1  |                  /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/management_agent.disable_metrics_collector.conf
```

However, it would be really convenient if I could avoid building a new image just for injecting an extra file to the image. I fount the [config](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/08-configs/) section of the compose file reference, but I cannot get it to work with `docker compose up` command. It seems that the file is injected to the container after the RabbitMQ server is started up, because it does not load it. Furthermore, the UID, GID, and permission settings are ignored.

**Can the config mechanism of the compose file work with `docker compose up`?**

I am using WSL2 on Windows 11 with Docker Desktop v4.17.0:

- Docker version 23.0.0, build e92dd87
- Docker Compose version v2.15.1

To use the compose file without building a new image of RabbitMQ I added a config section and used it the the relevant service (irrelevant parts removed):

```yaml
version: "3.9"

configs:
  rabbitmq_consumer_timeout_conf:
    file: ./docker/rabbit/rabbitmq.conf

services:
  manager: {...}
  worker: {...}
  rabbit:
    image: "rabbitmq:3.11.6"
    hostname: rabbit
    configs:
      - source: rabbitmq_consumer_timeout_conf
        target: /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/20-consumer_timeout.conf
        uid: "999"
        gid: "999"
        mode: 0440
```

Unfortunately, if this configuration is started with `docker compose up` RabbitMQ does not list the extra configuration file:

```
rabbit-1  |  Config file(s): /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/10-defaults.conf
rabbit-1  |                  /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/management_agent.disable_metrics_collector.conf
```

The `/etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/20-consumer_timeout.conf` file is present in the running container, however:

- Both the UID and GID is 1000 which are the values from the host (WSL2), so the `uid` and `gid` settings are ignored.
- The mode is 777 which is also the value from the host system (/mnt/c/...), so the `mode` setting is also ignored.
- I modified the mentioned Dockerfile to see if RabbitMQ would load the config file with the `uid`, `gid` and `mode` above and it successfully loaded it, so it seems that the config file is not copied there in time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`volume`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) to achieve this.

I use to do it for nginx configuration, but it should works the same for RabbitMQ.

```
nginx-service:
    image: nginx:1.23-alpine
    volumes:
        - ./nginx_proxy/conf/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

I find this easier to understand than `configs` blocks, and more convenient for development as you can easily modify the configuration file without the need to rebuild an image (but that's might be a matter of taste).

Comment: Unfortunately, the `/etc/rabbitmq/conf.d` directory in the image is not empty.